# Properties file of tomcat not overriding the application properties files

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I have some properties files in my spring boot application, but at the run time what I want is that those properties file from my server there I have provided the properties file path in my Catalina.sh.

but it's not overriding the application properties.

any lead would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a spring boot application, why are you not creating executable jar?

with the executable jar, you can overlay properties as

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=<path_to_overriden_prop_file>
```